# How can I render a component on any place inside angular 2 dom?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

For example I have a select component which opens a list. I want to implement the list inside the document body and connect it to the component which is rendered on any part of the DOM tree.

Also I want to be able to render multiple selects at once.

My current component works like this renders the list inside the `<select-cmp>` tag and because of that I have problems inside elements with translate 3d.

Any idea how I can inject a component inside the DOM and connect it to the current rendered `<select-cmp>` so I could destroy it when the `<select-cmp>` is removed from the DOM ?

Comment: are you asking about partial rendering?

Comment: No, I want to have the ability to "connect" two components. For exemple I have a <select-cmp> a select has the current selection as input and a list inside it. I want to decouple the list from the actual <select-cmp> I want to render the actual list in the DOM tree inside an overlay and compute his position to be under the select input. Which means I will not have problems to render the select component in elements with transform3d or with overflow hidden.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to connect what?